# Many seeders available, few connected

Tags: utorrent

This is an old question, but so far I have not seen a satisfactory answer.

**Why does uTorrent show dozens of seeders / lechers available, but only connect with just a few?**

In the example below, uTorrent shows **11 seeders available**, but **only connects with 5**. The same with peers, 39 available, but only connects with 6.

[image]

In this image we can see a detail of the connections:

[image]

In addition, my connection is **optical fiber**, high speed, I configured properly uTorrent not to limit the number of downloads, nor speed.

But after all, uTorrent insists on always connecting to fewer seeders/lechers.

Would anyone know how to improve this?

Comment: Could just be the age old problem of lots of people wanting the file but not wanting to share what they have...

Comment: The other peers are probably busy, not allowing further download requests.

Answer (score 2):

Because, [as per the uTorrent forum](https://forum.utorrent.com/topic/3047-reduce-your-number-of-connections-for-better-speed/), there's an optimum number of connections.

Doyen IT columnist [Robert X. Cringely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_X._Cringely) once reported he got best throughput with six torrents underway; more connections, less total speed, as per his experiments. (Wish I could find that blog post....)

Comment: This post is 2005. The rules remain the same from 13 years ago?

Comment: Old question, old issue. I have personally verified this using multiple clients; I get more throughput with 6-9 torrents in play.

Answer (score 1):

There is lot of uncertainty in the number in the parentheses as it is an estimate.
In the example, µTorrent most probably don't succeed to connect to the other 6 possible seeds.

The client tries and accept connections until it reaches one of the limits set in:
*Preferences (
<kbd>Ctrl+P</kbd>
) > Bandwidth*

- **Global maximum number of connections**
- **Maximum number of connected peers per torrent**

---

From *µTorrent User Manual (Press 
<kbd>F1</kbd>
) > Appendix A: The µTorrent Interface > Main Window > Torrent Jobs List*:

> - **Peers** displays the number of peers you are connected to, and **the number of peers in the swarm within the parentheses. The number of peers in the swarm is an** *estimate* **based on the maximum number of peers found either between the amounts reported by any tracker, or the number of peers µTorrent has encountered within its peer cache.** If the torrent job is stopped, and bt.scrape_stopped is enabled, µTorrent will show the maximum number of peers in the swarm as reported by the tracker scrapes.
> - **Seeds** displays the number of seeds you are connected to, and **the number of seeds in the swarm within the parentheses. The number of seeds in the swarm is an** *estimate* **based on the maximum number of seeds found either between the amounts reported by any tracker, or the number of seeds µTorrent has encountered within its peer cache.** If the torrent job is stopped, and bt.scrape_stopped is enabled, µTorrent will show the maximum number of seeds in the swarm as reported by the tracker scrapes.